# Anonymous function that matches signature () => Unit : Scala

Tags: scala, types, anonymous-function

Below lines of code are self explanatory

```
type a = () => Unit

def k(a_ : a) = {
  a_()
}

def g(): Unit = {
  println("Hello World")
}

k(g)
```

My question is how do I specify an anonymous function of type `a` while calling k?

Comment: In the same lines, `type a = Int => Unit`

`def k(a_ : a) = {`
  `a_`
`}`

`def g(i: Int): Unit = {`
  `println("Hello World "+i)`
`}`

`k(g)` , to have the above function `k(a_: a)` executed I will not be able to specify `a_()`, as it would expect Int parameter, how to have the function executed

Answer (score 2):

I hope these lines are also self-explanatory:

```
scala> k(() => println("Hello!")) //to your first question
Hello!
```

For the second question:

```
scala>  def k(i: Int)(a_ : a) = {
  a_(i)
}
k: (i: Int)(a_: Int => Unit)Unit

scala> k(5)(g)
Swami saranam 5
```

P.S. I wouldn't recommend to start `type` alias name with lower-case.

Comment: 2nd is that you have to specify your input `i` anyway, so you need some function to take it anyway - so I written `print` function for that - it takes `i` and calls composition of `k` and `g` with that `i`

Comment: but my `type a = Int => Unit` is different this time and in the function body of `k` cannot have `a_()` to get the function executed, sorry if I sound confused

Comment: just add one more paramater to the `k` to make it work - I've updated the answer with example